# Как почистить POST после обработки формы на странице? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

После отправки формы вызывается метод, который обрабатывает ее и отправляет данные в БД. Но когда обновляешь страницу запрос остается и форма заново обрабатывается и добавляется еще одна запись в БД. Как избавиться от этого?

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    Review::create($request->all());
    $pizza = Pizza::find($request->pizza_id);
    $reviews = Review::all()->where("pizza_id", $request->pizza_id);
    return view('pizza.show', compact(['pizza', 'reviews']));
}
```

Comment: насколько я знаю это сам браузер будет отсылать данные еще раз вне зависимости от пост. может return back(); поможет?

Comment: спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

В каждом POST запросе делать либо `return back();` либо редирект на любой другой произвольный маршрут.